# Return handle from .dll called using Python ctypes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to communicate with an oscilloscope using Python via a .dll provided by the manufacturer and Ctypes. I'm a novice to C so I might be missing something obvious, but I can't seem to get the more complicated function calls right.

I have got access to the .dll file and the .h file.

### Excerpt from the .h file:

```c
typedef long ScHandle;

...

int ScOpenInstrument(int wire, char* address, ScHandle* rHndl);
```

### My python code:

```py
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.WinDLL("ScAPI.dll")

# Define types
ScHandle = ctypes.c_long

# Define function argument types
lib.ScOpenInstrument.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.POINTER(ScHandle)]
lib.ScStart.argtypes = [ScHandle]

# Init library
ret = lib.ScInit()

# Open instrument
wire = ctypes.c_int(7)
addr = ctypes.c_char_p("91SB21329".encode("utf-8"))
handle = ScHandle(0)

ret = lib.ScOpenInstrument(wire, addr, ctypes.byref(handle))
```

The function is supposed to return a handle to the oscilloscope but instead I get the error:

*ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (12 bytes in excess)*

Answer (score 0):

According to [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - Calling functions](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions) (**emphasis** is mine):

> ...
>
> **The same exception is raised when you call an `stdcall` function with the `cdecl` calling convention, or vice versa**:
>
> ```
> >>> cdll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(None) # doctest: +WINDOWS
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
> ValueError: Procedure probably called with not enough arguments (4 bytes missing)
> >>>
>
> >>> windll.msvcrt.printf(b"spam") # doctest: +WINDOWS
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
> ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (4 bytes in excess)
> >>>
> ```
>
> To find out the correct calling convention you have to look into the C header file or the documentation for the function you want to call.
>
> ...

Seems like you're using the wrong calling convention (this error also states that you're running the *32bit* *Python*). To correct it, use:

```
lib = ctypes.CDLL("ScAPI.dll")
```

Also, you can shorten *addr* initialization:

```
addr = ctypes.c_char_p(b"91SB21329")
```